# How to call a function on click of date in html 5 datepicker input type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, meteor, angularjs-ng-model

I had a html5 date-time picker.Now on mouseclick(select) of date from date picker I want to call a function.I wonder how can we do that in angular js ...can
someone help me.

html:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">
 <input class="form-control" type="datetime" date-time auto-close="true" view="date" 
  min-view="date" format="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="$root.Details.date" value = "{{dob}}">
 </div>
```

Js

```
class CreateCustomerCtrl {
constructor($scope,$rootScope,$http,$state,$reactive,$timeout,Notification)
{

//logic here
}
export default angular.module('createCustomer', [
angularMeteor
])
.component('newCustomer', {
templateUrl: 'client/customer/new-customer.html',
 controller:['$scope','$rootScope','$http','$state','$reactive','$timeout','Notification'
,customerCtrl]});
```

So on select of date I want to call a function.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-change="yourFunc()"` event on input with `ng-model="myDate"` for binding value and inside function you can put your logic.

Comment: Tried this but didnt worked.FUnction is not getting called

Comment: $scope.yourFunc=function(){
}
have you tries this ?

Comment: Sorry I tried  this and didnt work ,the function is not getting called

Comment: is it possible to call a function from ng-model.If yes any idea of how we can do that here

Comment: Not possible ng-model is for data binding

Answer (score 0):

You should try `<input type="date" onchange="return function(this) />;"` and `return` your function to do whatever you want to.